# ssh server is rejecting public key

Tags: debian, ssh, linux-mint, key-authentication, putty

Sometimes I need to login on my Linux Mint 19 PC remotely via ssh. To make this more secure I try to switch to use Public Key authentication (as I already use it on my raspberries).

Basically the authentication works. But only if I logged in via GUI previously. After a fresh start of the system, the ssh server denies the public key authentication.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Encrypted home directory?

Comment: Are you using `ssh-agent` and does your agent have _many_ keys loaded?